# Navigate through a list passing objects from the list to a global method c++

Tags: c++, list, loops, visual-c++, iterator

I need to add obejcts to a list (for now they are just hard coded objects in main)

```
int main ()
{
// create objects of type Point, passing different x and y values to the contructor

Point point1 (7,5); // new point object point1 with value x=2.5, y=5.3
Point point2 (4,8); // second point obejct 
Point point3 (8,9); // third point object
Point point4 (10,5);//fourth point object
Point point5 (6,8);//fifth point
Point point6 (4,7);//sixth point
}
```

add them to a list one by one using push_back

```
list<Point>pointList ; // stl list that will contain my objects.
pointList.push_back(point1);//adds the obejcts to the list from the back each time {point1}
pointList.push_back(point2);//{point1, point2} < point2 pushed_back
pointList.push_back(point3);//{point, point}
pointList.push_back(point4);
pointList.push_back(point5);
pointList.push_back(point6);
```

now what i need to do is pass objects 3 at a time to this method >

```
static void calculateF (Point p1, Point& p2, Point p3)// point2 needs to be a reference otherwise f is just changed locally. 
double F ; // 

double xPoint1 = p1.getX(); // x value of object p1
double yPoint1 = p1.getY(); // y value of object p1
double xPoint2 = p2.getX(); // x value of object p2
double yPoint2 = p2.getY(); // y coordinates of object p2 
double xPoint3 = p3.getX(); // x coordinates of obejct p3
double yPoint3 = p3.getY(); // y coorinates of obejct p3

//equation for working out f from these six values
//temp variables to store the length of the triangles sides.
double p2p3 = sqrt (((xPoint2 - xPoint3)*(xPoint2 - xPoint3)) + ((yPoint2 - yPoint3)*(yPoint2 - yPoint3))); //length point2 to point1 (PR in assingment notes)
cout << "p1p2 is = " << p2p3 << endl; // print the value of p2p3 (PR) 
double p1p2 = sqrt (((xPoint1 - xPoint2)*(xPoint1 - xPoint2)) + ((yPoint1 - yPoint2)*(yPoint1 - yPoint2))); //length point1 to point 2 (LP in assingment notes)
cout << "p1p2 is = " << p1p2 << endl;
double p1p3 = sqrt (((xPoint1 - xPoint3)*(xPoint1 - xPoint3)) + ((yPoint1 - yPoint3)*(yPoint1 - yPoint3)));//length of point1 to point 3 (LR in assigment notes) 
cout << "hypotenuse p1p3 is = " << p1p3 << endl; 

F = p1p2 + p2p3 - p1p3 ; //equation for f
//cout << "importance factor is " << F << endl ;
p2.setF(F); //  setting F to f in class
}
```

now i understand that i could just pass one at a time like 
calculatef(point1,point2,point3);
calculatef(point2.point3,point4);
etc..............

its not actually using the list at all to pass them, which is what i need to do. Add points the the list and use the list to pass each point to the calculateF method.

If thats a really round about way of asking the question i apoligise. I just included everything so it could be put into context.

Thanks in advance competent programmers

Answer (score 0):

Since a list is implemented as a doubly linked list you may be better suited using a vector (as you can gain access to individual elements very easily and efficiently using a vector...).

You could use the following code example in order to perform what you wish

```
std::vector<Point> vec;
vec.push_back( Point(0,0));
// Push back all other points...
for( int i = 0; i < ( vec.size() - 2 ); i++ )
{
    calculateF( vec[i], vec[i+1], vec[i+2] );
}
```

I hope this helps...

Comment: Hi Rich, thanks for the response. Now i was guided to using lists as i need to erase the points with the lowest importance factor each time i traverse the list. So i need to rebuild it each time too after i have removed the least significant point in the shape, then run it again until a user specified amount of points remain (the points are a coordinates of a shape boundary)   The line vec.push_back(new Point (0,0)); does not seem to be working either.

Comment: Ok, so is vec.push_back(point(0,0)) used to add items continuously to the list? and then the for loop passes all the obejcts then added to the list to the calculate f method? could you break it down a little more please. sorry for the noobishness of my comments

Comment: Yes, you add all the points you want to the vector, and yes, the for loop then passes the elements of the vector to the calculateF function as you detailed in your initial post.  It works as follows:
`calculateF( element1, element2, element3 );`
`calculateF( element2, element3, element4 );`
until it is complete...

What errors are being thrown?

Comment: 1>c:\users\max\documents\_uni_corsework\year 2 (undergraduate)\c++\cppprojects\assignment\assignment_practicevectors.cpp(126): error C3867: 'std::vector<_Ty>::size': function call missing argument list; use '&std::vector<_Ty>::size' to create a pointer to member
1>c:\users\max\documents\_uni_corsework\year 2 (undergraduate)\c++\cppprojects\assignment\assignment_practicevectors.cpp(126): error C2296: '-' : illegal, left operand has type 'unsigned int (__thiscall std::vector<_Ty>::* )(void) throw() const'

Comment: i would post the whole code but not enough room in the comments

Comment: can we do someting where we can just cout the contents of the list to see if its adding correctly

Comment: To output the contents of the vector you must simply perform the following:

`for( int i = 0; i < vec.size(); i++ ) { std::cout << vec[i].getX() << vec[i].getY() << std::endl; }`

Comment: why are we using std:: infront of all cout? ps im using visual studio

Comment: the ouput is simply 00. so the objects are not being added to the vector

Comment: I use `std::` to qualify all structures and references to structures contained in the std:: namespace.  Mainly force of habit on my part, as I prefer to explicitly state where each structure comes from in the code...
Are you using `push_back()` for each of your point objects you have created?  As I provided the sample code not to use straight out of the box and have fully functioning but to try and nudge you along the right direction :).

Answer (score 0):

You can also do something more generic with vector-iterators, like;

```
void calculateF (std::vector<Point>::iterator from_a, 
                 std::vector<Point>::iterator to_b   )
{
   for (std::vector<Point>::iterator i=from_a; i != to_b; ++i) {
      // ... do something with i->x and i->y
    }
}

main()
{
    ...
    calculateF(vec.begin()+0, vec.begin()+3);
    calculateF(vec.begin()+3, vec.begin()+6);
    ...
}
```